# Tabs not showing

Tags: safari

My safari browser tabs are all blank.. Any ideas on how to make the titles reappear?[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting safari?

Answer (score 1):

Right click inside Safari, click *Show Page Source*, then check if there is a title tag:

```
<title>safari - Tabs not showing - Ask Different</title>
```

If there is, it should work, if not, then it might be a 3rd party extension. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to bring up the Preferences, then click on the Extensions tab. Disable all extensions then restart Safari by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to Quit. Then open it up again.

If the title appears, enable 1 extension at a time to see which one triggers it. If you don't have any extensions and it worked, then it simply needed a restart.

Let us know if this worked! :)